# Apply a function dynamically to n different objects

Tags: r

I am working in R.

I have `n` different objects all with the same name structure `paste0("df",j) for j = 1,...,n` (i.e. `df1`, `df2`, `df3`, ...).

To each one of them, I want to apply a user-defined function (let's assume its only argument is the object itself).

Usually, I use this:

```
for (i in (1:n)){
 assign(paste0("u", 1), function(eval(parse(text = paste0("df",i)))))
}
```

Nevertheless, I get the following error:

```
Error in parse(text = paste0("df", j)) : 
  unused argument (text = paste0("df", j))
```

Does anyone have a solution for this? I would appreciate if the solution would not involve the `eval(parse(text = paste0("something"))))` trick which I personally find not that practical.

Comment: You need to post something reproducible.  What you posted gives a different error than the one you reported.  We don't need your full user-defined function, just something we can run to see the error you were getting (which doesn't really makes sense, since `text` *is* an argument to `parse()`.   Maybe you created your own function named `parse`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

1. Get the objects names with that name structure into a character vector;
2. `mget` the data sets;
3. `lapply` the function to each data set.

The code would be:

```
df_names <- ls(pattern = "^df\\d+$")
u_list <- lapply(mget(df_names), function(DF){
  # do this and that
  DF[["x"]] <- DF[["x"]] + 100
  DF
})
u_list
#$df1
#    x
#1 101
#2 102
#3 103
#4 104
#5 105
#
#$df2
#    x
#1 111
#2 112
#3 113
#4 114
#5 115
```

If the names of the result dataframes need to be `"u"` followed by a number,

```
names(u_list) <- paste0("u", seq_along(u_list))
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:5)
df2 <- data.frame(x = 11:15)
```

Comment: thank you! The mget function does the job... However, it has a name attribute, i.e. df$1 etc... Is there a way to remove such name attribute?

Comment: @Vitomir To remove the names attribute just do `names(u_list) <- NULL`. If you want your own names, he last code line in the answer gives a way to do what the `assign` instruction in the question does.